# image as planes show shiny in render mode error

Tags: rendering, uv, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

In the render, my PNG image plane appears shiny and visible. I need light to brighten up, but I don't want to make my image plane shiny. Is there a way to get rid of this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower the *Metallic* and the *Specular* value down to 0?

[image]

If you don't want any shadow you can directly plug the *Image Texture* into the *Output* node, or *Image Texture > Emission > Output*.